# List Separator script

Tags: vbscript, windows-7

How can I change the List separator from the command line?

Normally I have to edit a field in: *Control Panel → Change keyboards or other input methods → Additional settings*

I would love to create a VBScript that I click which automatically changes from `,` to `;`, and another one that goes back.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A single script should suffice. The setting is stored in the registry value `HKCU\ControlPanel\International\sList` and can be toggled with something like this:

```
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

path = "HKCU\Control Panel\International\sList"

Set separator = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
separator.Add True , ";"
separator.Add False, ","

sh.RegWrite path, separator(sh.RegRead(path) = ","), "REG_SZ"
```

Comment: You are amazing - and also my hero

Answer (score 1):

An even easier way to do this is via a .bat file

open notepad, and save the below as semi.bat or whatever you want to call it.

```
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International" /f /v "sList" /t "REG_SZ" /d ";"
PAUSE
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\International" /f /v "sList" /t "REG_SZ" /d ","
```

This will allow you to open the .bat file it will change it to what you need then when you are finished it will change it back.