# Convert XLS to pipe delimited CSV file via command line

Tags: vb.net, excel, csv, vbscript

I found this code to convert xls to csv.

```
    if WScript.Arguments.Count < 2 Then
    WScript.Echo "Error! Please specify the source path and the destination. Usage: XlsToCsv SourcePath.xls Destination.csv"
    Wscript.Quit
    End If
    Dim oExcel
    Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Dim oBook
    Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
    call oBook.SaveAs(WScript.Arguments.Item(1), 6)
    oBook.Close False
    oExcel.Quit
    WScript.Echo "Done"
```

But I want pipe | delimiter.

I changed the value from 6 to 22 but the delimiter are TAB

```
    call oBook.SaveAs(WScript.Arguments.Item(1), 6)
```

Appreciate all your Help.

Ryl

Comment: I think you need to set your List Separator via your computer's Regional Settings. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27451930/list-separator-script You could change it in script, save the file, then change it back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little more elegant.  It changes the global delimiter saves the file and changes it back.

```
 Set oWshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")  


 if WScript.Arguments.Count < 2 Then
    WScript.Echo "Error! Please specify the source path and the destination. Usage: XlsToCsv SourcePath.xls Destination.csv"
    Wscript.Quit
    End If
   oWshShell.RUN "powershell.exe -noprofile  -window hidden -command  " &_
                                  "C:\XXXXX\stack\Pipe.ps1" ,0,True 

    Dim oExcel
    Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Dim oBook
    Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(Wscript.Arguments.Item(0))
    call oBook.SaveAs(WScript.Arguments.Item(1),6,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,True )

    oBook.Close False
    oExcel.Quit

  oWshShell.Run "powershell.exe -noprofile  -window hidden -command  " &_
                                   "C:\XXXXX\stack\Comma.ps1" ,0, True

    WScript.Echo "Done"
```

Comment: Create 2 files listed above
in Pipe.ps1 put
    Set-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\"Control Panel"\International -Name sList -Value "|"

in Comma.ps1
    Set-ItemProperty -Path HKCU:\"Control Panel"\International -Name sList -Value ","

Answer (score 0):

If you know the format of the spreadsheet you can use something like this.

```
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, Forappending = 8  

SheetName = "Sheet1"



fileDir = "C:\XXXXX\stack\"
fileOut = "Pipe.csv"

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objFile = oFSO.OpenTextFile(fileDir & fileOut, ForWriting,true)          

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open _
    ("C:\XXXX\stack\sample.xlsx")
  objExcel.Sheets(SheetName).Select  
    intRow = 1

Do Until objExcel.Cells(intRow,1).Value = ""
    lineOut  = objExcel.Cells(intRow, 1).Value & "|" & objExcel.Cells(intRow, 2).Value & "|" & objExcel.Cells(intRow, 3).Value
      objFile.writeline  lineOut

    intRow = intRow + 1
Loop

objExcel.Quit
```